# no-op/explicitly do nothing in go

Tags: go

I have a type method that mutates the type's fields. It takes no arguments and returns nothing. The bulk of the method is a `switch` block. I want to be able to "short-circuit" out of the `switch` block with a no-op. Before I refactored it into a type method, I would've just returned out of the function, but that's out. Removing the case would break the logic of the method--the `default` case mutates state, which I don't want to do if this case is matched. I need the equivalent of Python's `pass`, basically.

Code:

```
func (parser *Parser) endSectionName () {
    state = parser.State
    buffer = parser.buffer
    results = parser.results
    switch {
        case state.HasFlag(IN_ESCAPED) {
            // ???
        }
        case !inSection(state) {
            return state, NotInSectionError
        }
        case !state.HasFlag(IN_SECTION_NAME) {
            state.Reset()
            return state, errors.New("Parsing error: Not in section name")
        }
        default {
            state.RemoveFlag(IN_SECTION_NAME)
            s := buffer.String()
            results[s] = new(Section)
            buffer.Reset()
            return state, nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to `break`

Comment: Btw your example code doesn't compile in Go, you need colons `:` after the cases, e.g. `case state.HasFlag(IN_ESCAPED): { ...`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Unlike in other languages, in Go the control flow breaks at each `case` of a [`switch`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) statement, control doesn't flow into the next `case` unless it is explicitly "asked" for with the [`fallthrough`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Fallthrough_statements) statement.

And also a statement is not required after the `case` (it can be empty). See this example:

```
i := 3
switch i {
case 3:
case 0:
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

It will print nothing even though `i==3` and there is no statement after `case 3`.

Same as this:

```
i := 3
switch {
case i == 3:
case i == 0:
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/myySOENgCv).

Comment: It is also a good practice to add a comment à la `// Do nothing.` to make it more clear that we don't need any action in this case.